# Entity Framework crashes instead of throwing an exception for duplicate record with .NET 5

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have a ASP.NET 5 project which uses Entity Framework and consists of razor pages and few API endpoints. The project is code-first and I am having trouble with an Entity Framework call in one of my APIs.

I am adding a record Add(entity); followed by SaveChanges(); and the application just stops at SaveChanges without throwing any Exception. The debugger is still running, just the current execution stops. I can continue to make other API calls and access the website successfully.

I turned on logging for EF and see the following entry.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
INSERT INTO [preorder].[PreOrderInfo] ([CancelConfirmedTimestamp], [CancelTimestamp], [ConfirmedTimestamp], [IsEmailSent], [KioskRefId], [OrderAmount], [OrderCurrencyRefId], [OrderExpiryTimestamp], [OrderId], [OrderTimestamp], [PickUpTimestamp], [PreOrderStatusRefId], [QRCode], [TotpSecretKey], [TransactionTimeStamp], [TransferConfirmTimeStamp], [TransferKioskRefId], [TransferTimeStamp])
VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6, @p7, @p8, @p9, @p10, @p11, @p12, @p13, @p14, @p15, @p16, @p17);
SELECT [Id]
FROM [preorder].[PreOrderInfo]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT = 1 AND [Id] = scope_identity();
```

I replicated the query in Sql server management studio with the exact same data and correctly see the Duplicate Key Row Error.

```
INSERT INTO 
[preorder].[PreOrderInfo] ([CancelConfirmedTimestamp], [CancelTimestamp], [ConfirmedTimestamp], 
[IsEmailSent], [KioskRefId], [OrderAmount], [OrderCurrencyRefId], [OrderExpiryTimestamp], 
[OrderId], [OrderTimestamp], [PickUpTimestamp], [PreOrderStatusRefId], [QRCode], 
[TotpSecretKey], [TransactionTimeStamp], [TransferConfirmTimeStamp], [TransferKioskRefId], [TransferTimeStamp])
VALUES (null, null, null, 
0, 1, 17.93, 39, '27-Jan-2021 00:39:43', 
'202101190821', '18-Jan-2021 13:47:56', '25-Jan-2021 00:39:43', 1, '02001111', 
'552910', null, null, 0, null);
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Msg 2601, Level 14, State 1, Line 3
Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'preorder.PreOrderInfo' with unique index 'IX_PreOrderInfo_OrderId'. The duplicate key value is (202101190821).
The statement has been terminated.
```

I am not sure why EF does not handle this exception and crashes.

**--Edit--**

Code is attached below

```
var kiosk = dbHelper.AddOrder(newPreOrderDto, preOrderExpiryHours);

public Kiosk AddOrder(NewPreOrderDto newPreOrderDto, int orderExpiryInHours)
{
    var newPreOrder = _mapper.Map<PreOrderInfo>(newPreOrderDto);
    _unitOfWork.PreOrderInfo.Add(newPreOrder);
    _unitOfWork.Save();
}

This uses the standard Repository Pattern. The Repository pattern classes are all synchronous, without any await or async keywords in the project.
```

Also as soon as the API call freezes, the EF logger starts logging select commands to every table in my database. See log data below, where the 1st log entry is the ERR followed by strange select commands. This is running on my dev PC and no code is executing which could generate those select queries.

```
[16:11:01 ERR] Failed executing DbCommand (56ms) [Parameters=[@p0='?' (DbType = DateTime2), @p1='?' (DbType = DateTime2), @p2='?' (DbType = DateTime2), @p3='?' (DbType = Boolean), @p4='?' (DbType = Int32), @p5='?' (Precision = 12) (Scale = 5) (DbType = Decimal), @p6='?' (DbType = Int32), @p7='?' (DbType = DateTime2), @p8='?' (Size = 25) (DbType = AnsiString), @p9='?' (DbType = DateTime2), @p10='?' (DbType = DateTime2), @p11='?' (DbType = Int32), @p12='?' (Size = 25) (DbType = AnsiString), @p13='?' (Size = 8) (DbType = AnsiString), @p14='?' (DbType = DateTime2), @p15='?' (DbType = DateTime2), @p16='?' (DbType = Int32), @p17='?' (DbType = DateTime2)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SET NOCOUNT ON;
INSERT INTO [preorder].[PreOrderInfo] ([CancelConfirmedTimestamp], [CancelTimestamp], [ConfirmedTimestamp], [IsEmailSent], [KioskRefId], [OrderAmount], [OrderCurrencyRefId], [OrderExpiryTimestamp], [OrderId], [OrderTimestamp], [PickUpTimestamp], [PreOrderStatusRefId], [QRCode], [TotpSecretKey], [TransactionTimeStamp], [TransferConfirmTimeStamp], [TransferKioskRefId], [TransferTimeStamp])
VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6, @p7, @p8, @p9, @p10, @p11, @p12, @p13, @p14, @p15, @p16, @p17);
SELECT [Id]
FROM [preorder].[PreOrderInfo]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT = 1 AND [Id] = scope_identity();
[16:11:01 INF] Executed DbCommand (6ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT [a].[Id], [a].[AccessFailedCount], [a].[ConcurrencyStamp], [a].[Email], [a].[EmailConfirmed], [a].[FirstName], [a].[IsActive], [a].[JobRole], [a].[LastName], [a].[LockoutEnabled], [a].[LockoutEnd], [a].[NormalizedEmail], [a].[NormalizedUserName], [a].[PasswordHash], [a].[PhoneNumber], [a].[PhoneNumberConfirmed], [a].[SecurityStamp], [a].[TwoFactorEnabled], [a].[UserName], [a].[ValidFrom], [a].[ValidTo], [a].[Version3], [a].[Version4]
FROM [AspNetUsers] AS [a]
[16:11:01 INF] Executed DbCommand (15ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT [a].[Id], [a].[Name]
FROM [master].[AccessType] AS [a]
[16:11:01 INF] Executed DbCommand (7ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT [a].[Id], [a].[Description], [a].[ShortName]
FROM [master].[AccessModule] AS [a]
[16:11:01 INF] Executed DbCommand (9ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT [a].[Id], [a].[AccessModuleRefId], [a].[AdminAccess], [a].[ApplicationUserRefId], [a].[CITAccess], [a].[ViewAccess]
FROM [AccessControl] AS [a]
[16:11:01 INF] Executed DbCommand (5ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT [r].[Id], [r].[Code], [r].[CountryRefCode], [r].[IsActive], [r].[Name]
FROM [master].[Region] AS [r]
[16:11:01 INF] Executed DbCommand (18ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT [s].[Code], [s].[IsActive], [s].[Name], [s].[RegionRefId]
FROM [master].[Site] AS [s]
[16:11:01 INF] Executed DbCommand (2ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT [c].[Code], [c].[Code2], [c].[IsActive], [c].[Name]
FROM [master].[Country] AS [c]
[16:11:02 INF] Executed DbCommand (10ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT [k].[Id], [k].[Description], [k].[ShowComms]
FROM [master].[KioskStatus] AS [k]
[16:11:02 INF] Executed DbCommand (22ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT [k].[Id], [k].[Address], [k].[City], [k].[Code], [k].[CoinAcceptance], [k].[CoinsBin1], [k].[CoinsBin2], [k].[DisplayVideo], [k].[EURSme], [k].[GBP1Sme], [k].[GBP2Sme], [k].[GpsLat], [k].[GpsLon], [k].[HasErrored], [k].[IPAddress], [k].[ImageFileName], [k].[IsActive], [k].[IsHopperDisabled], [k].[IsInMaintenance], [k].[IsSummer], [k].[KioskLocationId], [k].[KioskName], [k].[KioskStatusRefId], [k].[KioskVersionRefCode], [k].[NotesBin1], [k].[Postcode], [k].[PreOrderEnabled], [k].[RateCurrencyTemplateRefId], [k].[SelfMaintenance], [k].[SiteRefCode], [k].[SleepTime], [k].[TransactionInProgress], [k].[USDSme], [k].[WakeTime]
FROM [master].[Kiosk] AS [k]
[16:11:02 INF] Executed DbCommand (8ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT [c].[Id], [c].[CountryRefCode], [c].[ISO], [c].[IsActive], [c].[IsOutCurrency], [c].[Name]
FROM [currencies].[Currency] AS [c]
[16:11:02 INF] Executed DbCommand (33ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT [b].[Id], [b].[CurrencyRefId], [b].[Description], [b].[ISO], [b].[IsActive], [b].[PaidOut], [b].[PrinterDescription], [b].[ValidFrom], [b].[ValidTo]
FROM [currencies].[BillValidatorCurrency] AS [b]
[16:11:03 INF] Executed DbCommand (15ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT [b].[Id], [b].[AllowStock], [b].[BillValidatorCurrencyRefId], [b].[BillValidatorCurrencyStatusRefId], [b].[DenominationTypeRefId], [b].[IsActive], [b].[Value]
FROM [currencies].[BillValidatorDenomination] AS [b]
[16:11:03 INF] Executed DbCommand (9ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT [b].[Id], [b].[Color], [b].[Description]
FROM [currencies].[BillValidatorCurrencyStatus] AS [b]
[16:11:03 INF] Executed DbCommand (7ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT [d].[Id], [d].[Name]
FROM [currencies].[DenominationType] AS [d]
[16:11:03 INF] Executed DbCommand (43ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT [d].[Id], [d].[CurrencyRefId], [d].[DenominationTypeRefId], [d].[Iso], [d].[KioskVersionRefCode]
FROM [currencies].[DispenserCurrency] AS [d]
[16:11:03 INF] Executed DbCommand (6ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT [d].[Id], [d].[DenominationValue], [d].[DispenserCurrencyRefId]
FROM [currencies].[DispenserDenominationMapping] AS [d]
[16:11:03 INF] Executed DbCommand (4ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT [h].[Id], [h].[KioskRefId], [h].[Ping], [h].[UptimeSince]
FROM [master].[HeartBeat] AS [h]
[16:11:03 INF] Executed DbCommand (162ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT [h].[Id], [h].[KioskRefId], [h].[Ping]
FROM [history].[HeartBeatHistory] AS [h]
[16:11:04 INF] Executed DbCommand (21ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT [c].[Id], [c].[Code], [c].[Description], [c].[Identifier]
FROM [master].[Charity] AS [c]
[16:11:04 INF] Executed DbCommand (62ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT [t].[Id], [t].[Name]
FROM [transactions].[TransactionDirection] AS [t]
[16:11:04 INF] Executed DbCommand (47ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT [t].[Id], [t].[KioskRefId], [t].[TimeStamp], [t].[TransactionDateTime], [t].[TransactionId], [t].[TransactionTypeRefId], [t].[Turnover]
FROM [transactions].[TransactionMaster] AS [t]
```

**--Edit 2--*

The Threads windows

[The point in the debugger where it will crash on step][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgoBc.png

[After step the current thread has terminated][2]
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mtzko.png

Comment: You sure you're not missing an `await` or something? Where's the code?

Comment: I have edited the post to add the code

Comment: The relevant code is still missing.

Comment: The entire code is a few hundred lines long. I have pasted the relevant code. Let me know what additional code you need. The repository pattern code is below if you need that.

public virtual void Add(T entity)
{
      _dbSet.Add(entity);
}


public void Save()
        {
            _db.SaveChanges();
        }

Comment: Did you attach the debugger and hit pause to see what code is running? also check threads window.

Comment: How about getting the basic code to work, with plain old `DbContext` and `DbSet<T>`, before writing all of these wrappers? By the way, `DbSet<T>` is an implementation of the repository pattern and `DbContext` is an implementation of the unit of work pattern.

Comment: Did you check primary or unique keys ? There may be duplication in the primary or unique keys

Comment: Yeah @AluanHaddad that's the plan, to revert to the base EF code, if no one here has encountered a similar problem. Btw opinions are divided whether to use a Repository Pattern over EF or not. I prefer using it, as over the months of project development, it abstracts away the database and entity logic.

Comment: @RandRandom I checked the Threads windows, but it does not point to any issues. I have updated Edit2, in the original post with the screenshots. Thanks

Comment: @RamilAliyev yes there is a duplicate key. If I pass a unique key the code executes fine. My problem is when the api call is made with a duplicate key, I am unable to catch the Exception

Comment: Yes it's a matter of opinion. It depends on the complexity of the application. I was saying you should test the scenario without the extra wrappers to help you debug

Comment: @AvinashTauro did you check Entity Framework's mappings ?

Comment: @RamilAliyev I am not sure what you mean by check the mappings. I ran a add-migration to verify, and my model - db mapping is correct.

Answer (score 0):

From the replies, I assume this is not a common issue. I got around this by checking for a duplicate record manually before trying to insert the new record.

This solved my problem now. When I have some time, I will try to deep-dive and figure out the actual issue.